Need to understand the difference between adding scope vs adding role to service account
My use case is very simple. Basically from VM communicate with Google Cloud Storage bucket. Communication means listing down what is inside, copy files, delete files etc.
I saw I can achieve this by two ways -

While creating the VM, add the read/write scope for Google Cloud Storage
While creating the VM, provide default scope, but give proper role to Service Account.

I tried both the approaches and was able to achieve my goal. But not sure what are the gotcas with each approach, what are the problem/risk I am introducing with each approaches?
Also not sure which is one best practice and which one should be used under which scenario. If you have any idea, can you please help me? Thanks !!

A good question that I'm unsure is adquately documented by Google.
OAuth scopes predate (and are complementary to) Cloud (!) IAM.
All Google cloud services support OAuth and OAuth scopes for Google APIs
Only Google Cloud services support Cloud IAM.
For Cloud services that expose OAuth scopes and support Cloud IAM, the authorization is effectively the intersection of the scopes and the IAM permissions.
For this reason, for Cloud services, it is common for the generic Cloud Platform scopes to be used and for IAM to be used to provide the effective authorization|permissions:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only

In your scenario, the VM is probably (!) using the Compute Engine default Service Account and this account (by default) has Editor role which grants a broad swath of permissions which include permission for Cloud Storage.
To answer your question succinctly:

OAuth scopes and Cloud IAM roles|permissions are always applied
When assigning OAuth scopes for Cloud services, consider the broad cloud-platform scope
If you experience OAuth scope issues with Cloud services, it could be because the OAuth scopes conflict with the IAM roles|permissions
Avoid using default (e.g. Compute Engine) Service Accounts


Good answer, adding with that that you sometime need OAuth token and sometime Identity token, and you have the full picture of the fucking security mess at Google!! :D :D :D

Adding the Read/Write scope during VM creation is very easy to configure than the latter but by using this method there will be potential security risk in case of VM compromising.
Using the Service Account and providing the least privilege permission is always the recommended practice for any kind of service in GCP or any cloud for that matter.
By granting only required Roles to the Service Account will help to limit the VM's operations to only what is necessary. So that your data will be protected and prevent unauthorized access.
So, in your case using the Service Account is best practice for using the Cloud storage bucket along with the Compute Engine.
Refer to these google official best practices of Service Accounts and Cloud storage buckets documentation for more information
